# Calculating Percentile of a data set

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Can anyone help me how to compute 25$^{\text{th}}$, 50$^{\text{th}}$, 75$^{\text{th}}$ and 90$^{\text{th}}$ perecentile of a dataset.

```
    data = {1.13, 1.24, 1.25, 1.27, 1.28, 1.29, 1.3, 1.36, 1.39, 1.42, 
  1.48, 1.48, 1.49, 1.49, 1.5, 1.5, 1.51, 1.52, 1.53, 1.54, 1.55}
```

Comment: `Quantile[data, #] & /@ {0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9}` See also `Quartiles[data]`

Comment: Another syntax variation allows a list of quantities: `Quantile[data, {1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 9/10}]`

Comment: Percentile is not exactly the same as Quantile, even if closely related. One issue, other than the obvious 100 scale factor, is that `"Percent"` is also a `Quantity` "Unit". Probably this should not be closed?

Comment: +5/-0 votes and a +3 vote answer, why should this stay closed?

Answer (score 5):

Percentile is closely related to fractile or [`Quantile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantile.html), except for the scaling 1 to 100 on the argument and the possibility that such arguments could be a `"Percent"`age unit from `Quantity`.

Here I define `Percentile` to also accept [`Quantity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html) with explicit `"Percent"` "Units" and also so it works in operator form.

```
ClearAll[Percentile];
Percentile[data_List, pc_Quantity]:= Quantile[data, QuantityMagnitude[pc/100, "Percent"]]
Percentile[data_List, pc_]:= Quantile[data, pc/100]
Percentile[pc_]:= Percentile[#,pc]&


Percentile[data, {25,50,75,90}]
(* {1.29,1.48,1.5,1.53} *)

Percentile[data, Quantity[99, "Percent"]]
(* 1.55 *)

Percentile[25] @ data
(* 1.29 *)
```

[image]